# Linq - Distinct list of object fill in int array

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to do, get randomly one of "list of objects" from all lists.
I am getting `NullReferenceException` I also tried List couldn't make it work.

```
List<BL.Test.Test> Tests = BL.Test.GET.TestGroup(CategoryId);

// NullReferenceException on the line below:
int[] Groups = Tests.Select(d => d.TestGroupId).Distinct().ToArray(); 

Session["TestGroup"] = Tests.Select(t => t.TestGroupId = Groups[rnd.Next(Groups.Length)]);
```

[image: Tests not null]

Comment: Use the debugger to figure out what is null.

Comment: Can you please provide us the "Test" class and the return value of the "TestGroup" method?

Comment: I cant use debugger in lambda

Comment: Please check what `Tests.Select(d => d.TestGroupId)` returns.

Comment: The property `get` accessor for `TestGroupId` throws an exception. This is an example why it is confusing when `get` accessors throw; they should not.

Comment: Yes there was problem about TestGroupId! Thanks Thomas, sometimes you trust too much and miss simple things :)

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, `BL.Test.GET.TestGroup` is the method which returns `null`.

That's the most probable explanation for a `NullReferenceException` in a second line of your example.

And if `Select`, `Distinct` and `ToArray` are extension methods declared in `System.Linq`, this reason is the only possible, so check your method.

**UPD**.

Sorry guys, I am wrong.

`TestGroupId` member of `BL.Test.Test` class is missed.

**UPD-2**

This is a good example of community debugging question. As I know it is not appreciated here

Comment: How did you checked that?

Answer (score 0):

Since `TestGroupId` would be `null` hence `null.Distinct()` throws `NullArgumentReference` exception.
Change ur code with following code:

```
List<BL.Test.Test> Tests = BL.Test.GET.TestGroup(CategoryId);

int[] Groups = Tests.Where(d=>d.TestGroupId.HasValue).Select(d => d.TestGroupId).Distinct().ToArray(); 

Session["TestGroup"] = Tests.Select(t => t.TestGroupId = Groups[rnd.Next(Groups.Length)]);
```

Make use of `HasValue` to find if `TestGroupId` has some value.